# What is the proof that for an integer $x$, $\phi(x^2) = x \phi(x)$, where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

What is the proof that for an integer $x$, $\phi(x^2) = x  \phi(x)$, where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function?

I know about $\phi(ab) = \phi(a)  \phi(b)$ when $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, but for $x = a = b$,
the $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(x,x) = x \neq 1$, so how do I show that $\phi(x^2) = x \phi(x)$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132252/how-to-prove-that-φn2-n-φn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How many numbers between $0$ and $x$ are coprime with $x^2$? How many numbers between $x$ and $2x$ are coprime with $x^2$? Between $2x$ and $3x$? Between ...

Adding up all of these intervals, how many numbers between $0$ and $x^2$ are coprime with $x^2$?

Comment: x-1 numbers between 0 and x are coprime with $x^2$.  x-1 numbers between x and 2x are coprime with $p^2$.  x-1 numbers between 2x and 3x are coprime with $x^2$. So then we have 'x' groups of (x-1) --> x * (x-1). Thanks! I'll mark this as correct

Comment: @Knocker379 not $x-1$ unless $x$ is $1$ or prime.  But $\phi(x)$

Comment: @Henry They changed the post from being about a prime to a general integer (natural number, presumably). My guess is they got the two mixed up in this comment.

Comment: Another way of thinking about the pieces of this argument: (1) show that $\gcd(m,x^2)=1$ iff $\gcd(m,x)=1$ (argument: $\gcd(m,x)\leq\gcd(m,x^2)\leq\left(\gcd(m,x)\right)^2$ ); (2) use the fact that $\gcd(m,x)=\gcd(m-x,x)$.